# to parse xml node children values under same tagname

Tags: qt

I have two nodes `PW_KeyGrip` and `PW_PalmerGrasp` and the node `children` names are same in both the nodes.

```
<PW_KeyGrip>
  <PW_p1_EDC>173</PW_p1_EDC>
  <PW_p2_EDC>78</PW_p2_EDC>
  <PW_p2_FDS>196</PW_p2_FDS>
 </PW_KeyGrip>
 <PW_PalmerGrasp>
  <PW_p1_EDC>202</PW_p1_EDC>
  <PW_p1_APB>118</PW_p1_APB>
  <PW_p2_EDC>86</PW_p2_EDC>
 </PW_PalmerGrasp>
```

earlier, I used to search by tag name in order to select the value as:

```
root.elementsByTagName("PW_p1_EDC").at(0).firstChild().nodeValue()
```

Now since I have two values under same tag name. can you show me a way to select both the values under same tag name separately?

for example:

1. How to select `PW_p1_EDC` under `PW_KeyGrip`
2. How to select `PW_p1_EDC` under `PW_PalmerGrasp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple function to retrieve the node value under a given tag name:

```
int findValue(QDomElement const& root, QString const& name)
{
    QDomElement element = root.firstChildElement(name);
    return element.firstChildElement("PW_p1_EDC").firstChild().nodeValue().toInt();
}
```

Then you would have to call it like that:

```
    qDebug() << "PW_KeyGrip: " << findValue(root, "PW_KeyGrip");
    qDebug() << "PW_PalmerGrasp: " << findValue(root, "PW_KeyGrip");
```

If you want to find the values without the exact path, you could take a look to XPath and `QXmlQuery`